# Union types and "currying" / partial application style APIs

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface:

```
interface IFactory<T> extends Function {
    (...args: any[]): (((...args: any[]) => T)|T);
}
```

The following code snippet causes an error:

> ts] Type '((...args: any[]) => IKatana) | IKatana' is not assignable to type 'IKatana'. Type '(...args: any[]) => IKatana' is not assignable to type 'IKatana'. Property 'hit' is missing in type '(...args: any[]) => IKatana'.
>   (property) NinjaWithUserDefinedFactory._katana: IKatana

```
@injectable()
class NinjaWithUserDefinedFactory implements INinja {

    private _katana: IKatana;
    private _shuriken: IShuriken;

    public constructor(
        @inject("IFactory<IKatana>") katanaFactory: IFactory<IKatana>,
        @inject("IShuriken") shuriken: IShuriken
    ) {
        this._katana = katanaFactory(); // error!
        this._shuriken = shuriken;
    }

    public fight() { return this._katana.hit(); };
    public sneak() { return this._shuriken.throw(); };

}
```

Sometimes the factories can be invoked more than once using configuration. This also causes problems:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

```
class Engine {
    constructor(type: string, cc: number) {}
}


let engineFactory: IFactory<Engine> = (type: string) => (cc: number) => {
    return new Engine(type, cc);
};

let dieselEngine = engineFactory("diesel");
let dieselEngine300cc = dieselEngine(300); // error!
let dieselEngine320cc = dieselEngine(320); // error!
```

Any ideas about how to overcome this problem?

### Update

The typescript team is working on [Variadic Kinds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) which will solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following signature you have :

```
interface IFactory<T> extends Function {
    (...args: any[]): (((...args: any[]) => T)|T);
}
```

A simpler version would be:

```
interface IFactory<T> {
    (...args: any[]): (IFactory<T>|T);
}
```

Where you are basically saying that calling an instance of `IFactory` can give you another factory or `T`.

Based on that if `dieselEngine` is an `IFactory` *there* is no guarantee that calling it gives `T` or another `IFactory` as far as the compiler is concerned. Hence using the result of `dieselEngine(foo)` as a function is an error:

```
engineFactory("diesel")(300); // Error
```

## Fix

As should be clear from the above analysis you will need to specify the number of calls *upfront*. You can simplify it into a 2 call factory:

```
interface IFactory<T,C> {
    (type:string): (configuration:C) => T;
}

class Engine {
    constructor(type: string, cc: number) {}
}


let engineFactory: IFactory<Engine,number> = (type: string) => (cc: number) => {
    return new Engine(type, cc);
};

let dieselEngine = engineFactory("diesel");
let dieselEngine300cc = dieselEngine(300); // Okay!
let dieselEngine320cc = dieselEngine(320); // Okay!
```